# TestNG beforeGroups is not getting executed

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a problem with testNG @beforeGroups annotations.
I tried to create a simple example to check the order in which the annotations are executed. My problem is that I cannot get beforeGroups (and afterGroups) to occur.

My code:

OrderTest.java

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class OrderTest {
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite() {
    System.out.println("1. Before Suite");
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    System.out.println("2. Before Test");
}

@BeforeGroups(groups = "group1") 
public void beforeGroups1() {
    System.out.println("3. Before Groups");
}

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    System.out.println("4. Before Class");
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("5. Before Method");
}

@Test(groups= "group1") 
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("Test 1");
}

@Test(groups = {"group2"})
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("Test 2");
}

@Test
public void test3() {
    System.out.println("Test 3");
}

@Test
public void test4() {
    System.out.println("Test 4");
}

@Test
public void test5() {
    System.out.println("Test 5");
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod() {
    System.out.println("7. After Method");
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() {
    System.out.println("8. After Class");
}

@AfterGroups(groups="Group1")
public void afterGroups1() {
    System.out.println("9. After Groups1");
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    System.out.println("10. After Test");
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite() {
    System.out.println("11. afterSuite");
}
}
```

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
 <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
   <classes>
     <class name="package.OrderTest"/>
   </classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Results I'm getting

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
1. Before Suite
2. Before Test
4. Before Class
5. Before Method
Test 1
7. After Method
5. Before Method
Test 2
7. After Method
5. Before Method
Test 3
7. After Method
5. Before Method
Test 4
7. After Method
5. Before Method
Test 5
7. After Method
8. After Class
10. After Test
11. afterSuite
```

My question is, is there an way to make beforeGroups to happen?

Edit 9/9:
After adding the following piece to the testng.xml

```
<groups>
    <run>
        <include name="group1" />
    </run>
</groups>
```

It now outputs

```
3. Before Groups
Test 1
```

What I'd like to do is to make it run also the beforeSuite, beforeClass and other methods, is there anything else I can do to achieve that other than adding an group for every test?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still in trouble, but I can help you with that.
If you run your class in eclipse or IntelliJ as usual, the test execution ignores the group for execution and hence executes all the tests specified in the class without hesitation.

In case you want to check the 'groups' functionality, you have two options.

In IntelliJ, Run >> Edit Configurations... >> Configuration Tab, Test Kind: select Group >> Type your group (in your case "group1") >> Apply >> OK.
Now you just need to select the option "group1" that now is available in your Navigation Test Menu (next to the green arrow to run your tests) and run it.

There is another option, Running groups through an XML file called testng.xml, but can be more complex. In case you need more information related to this, here you have this helpful link:
https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-test-groups/

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
I tried to follow the xml guide you linked, it now run the before group and the test, but the output is:

3. Before Groups
Test 1

so it skip the beforeSuite, beforeMethod etc, is there a way to also run them?